# return sort by name error in meteor Js?

Tags: meteor

i need help for return client list from mongo Db using sort by name .here is below is my code verify and suggest me.

```
 client js:
Template.clientedit.clientList = function () 
    {
       console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> clientList "+H_client.find().count());

       return H_client.find({}, {sort: [[ name: "asc" ]]});

    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `name` is a property of `H_client` documents, this should work:

```js
return H_client.find({}, {sort: {name: 'asc'}});
```